# Attributes in meta tags in Grails being auto escaped

Tags: grails, tags

I was having a problem with meta attributes being double escaped in Grails, so for instance:
`<meta name="title" content="${'bla bla "bla"'.encodeAsHTML()}" />`
was becoming:
`<meta name="title" content="bla bla &amp;quot;bla&amp;quot;">`
Obviously removing encodeAsHTML() stops the double escape but it is strange as nothing else auto escaped, and not I'm sure where else things might be automatically escaped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out `meta`, `title` and `body` tag's attributes have `.encodeAsHTML()` called on them within `SiteMeshTagLib.groovy`.

This should really be documented somewhere, because I couldn't find any mention of it and thought it might be a bug.