# Grails UTF8 encoding in meta tags

Tags: grails, character-encoding

My grails website correctly displays UTF8 characters, for example the character "è", but fails to display them correctly in the meta tags; for example in the meta description the same charecter is displayed as `"&egrave;"` .
I read the strings from a text file encoded in UTF-8

What could be the problem?

Grails version is 2.2.1

**UPDATE**

I have the same problem even simply hardcoding a string in the meta description. The GSP file is seen as ISO-8859-2 encoded but I seem unable to convert it to UTF-8

Comment: I created an issue on Jira http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10236

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to disable the preprocessing of gsp pages by the sitemesh ?

In Config.groovy:

```
grails.views.gsp.sitemesh.preprocess = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with a TagLib

```
class SimpleTagLib {

 def unescaped = { attrs ->
      out << attrs.value  
  }

}
```

---

```
<meta content="${g.noEncode(value:'è')}" property="og:video" />
```

Comment: Not working for me. I found this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209240/attributes-in-meta-tags-in-grails-being-auto-escaped and the problem seem to be that encodeAsHTML() is always called on meta tags. I solved it removing encodeAsHTML() in SitemeshTagLib and rebuilding grails. Any idea on why your solution isn't working in my case? It would be a much better solution

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has trouble with this as me, I've solved it by creating a taglib that outputs the whole meta tag in this way:

Taglib definition

```
def metaTag = { attrs ->
    out << '<meta name="' + attrs.name + '" content="' + attrs.value + '"/>'
}
```

And I use it then in a .gsp file like this:

```
<p:metaTag name="description" value="+ěšřčžáéíáý"></p:metaTag>
```